# powershell - positional error if move files/folders from a text list

Tags: powershell

I try to move my folders and files from a text list but i have this error, i use windows server 2012

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Content x:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\filestocopy.txt | ForEach-Objec
t {move-item $_ X:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\--completati}
Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Village'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content x:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\filestocopy.txt |  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

**Village is a part of path..why it give me like an positional error?**

*Inside filestocopy.txt file i have this:*

```
X:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\hitman 2
X:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\Jak 3.rar
X:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\James Cameron's Dark Angel PAL PS2DVD
X:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\Kh_1.iso
X:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\Marvel La Grande Alleanza.rar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `'` or `"` symbols if the path or file name contains spaces or characters that the command line can be interpreted as a command.

Example: `Get-Content "x:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\filestocopy.txt" | ForEach-Object {move-item $_ "X:\TNT Village - psp, psx - 2 parte\ps2\downloads\--completati"}`